# Facebook Graph API (v.3.1) Marketing API: use two paramaters with Campaign Insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to return campaign insights in the Facebook Marketing API and show the results aggregated for each day and broken down by country.

I'm trying

```
act_xxxx/?fields=campaigns{name,insights}&time_increment=1&breakdowns=country
```

but the country and time_increment paramaters don't seem to affect the results.

I've had success with EITHER time_increment of breakdowns if I don't use the ?fields paramater but then I'm not aggregating at the level I want and can still only use one paramater.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this one out:

```
act_xxx/insights?fields=account_name,campaign_name,date_start,date_stop,spend,reach,impressions,cpc,inline_link_clicks,frequency,ctr,cost_per_inline_link_click,inline_link_click_ctr&breakdowns=country&time_increment=1&level=campaign
```

The key things I was missing were:

- define the level of aggregation in the ?level paramater return the
- Return insights edge before the ?fields paramater rather than through field
  extension as I did in my example.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is

```
act_xxxx?fields=campaigns{name,insights.time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}).time_increment(1).breakdowns(country)}
```

This one fetches all campaigns name and insights between the date interval in day by day manner breaking down according to countries

you can use {} for subfields like

```
campaigns{ads{name,insights,adcreatives{image_url}}}
```

you can use . and () for parameters like; always make sure you use you use fields only after parameters like this order .(){}

```
campaigns.limit(1).time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}).time_increment(1).breakdowns(country){ads{name,insights.time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}).time_increment(1).breakdowns(country),adcreatives{image_url}}}
```