# Meta Graph API get country

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have the following

```
act_ID/campaigns?fields=name,country,insights{reach,impressions,frequency,spend,unique_clicks,cpm,cost_per_action_type}
```

but it doesn't actually show countries. Why?
Does it just work with AD_SET_ID? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/insights/

Comment: `country` is one of the insights metrics, so it belongs _into_ `insights{...}` together with the rest of them.

Comment: If I use /insights?country,fields=campaign_name,reach,impressions,frequency,spend,actions,cost_per_action_type,cpm,cpc,ctr&date_preset=this_year&level=campaign
I don't see country in the output

Comment: Who said you should change the whole request structure? `act_ID/campaigns?fields=name,insights{country,reach,impressions,...` And if that doesn't give you any country info - then perhaps you need to select a different _breakdown_ to begin with.

Comment: 'campaigns?fields=name,insights{country,reach,impressions}' gives country is not valid for fields param, so I feel confused on what to try

Comment: Can you please quote that error message _verbatim_, instead of giving your own paraphrased version?

Comment: _"Does it just work with AD_SET_ID?"_ - have you tried the syntax on that level, instead of `act_ID/campaigns`?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671812/facebook-graph-api-v-3-1-marketing-api-use-two-paramaters-with-campaign-insig